# No valid request transport found

Tags: javascript, ios, oauth, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I keep getting this error:
[image: screenshot]

I am trying to build a social sharing app. Basically you go on the app and send out a tweet or a facebook post or something. But I need to get OAuth done (I am fairly new here, so sorry if this is a easy question).

I have tried:

- [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth)
- [oauth-js](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js)

But both return this error.

Here is the code I tried:

Attempt 1:

```
Ti.include('oauth.js');

//Using popup (option 1)
OAuth.popup('facebook')
.done(function(result) {
  //use result.access_token in your API request 
  //or use result.get|post|put|del|patch|me methods (see below)
  console.log(result);
})
.fail(function (err) {
  //handle error with err
  console.log(err);
});
```

Attempt 2:

```
Ti.include('auth_module.js');
/* Init Auth Module */
Ti.App.authModule = AuthModule.init({
  client_id:       "5JTdUPh0URR8zwTtxOw1IWl35",
  client_secret:   "0KzAG6uWGBzsz5hcQN3wCEuFoWDY13bWjHoYJnUDMAjT0vsHre",
  redirect_uri:    "http://demisocial.dev:3000/",
  auth_server_url: "http://demisocial.dev:3000/"
});

var url = Alloy.CFG.server + Alloy.CFG.urls.update_status;
url.replace("--status--", "This%20is%20a%20test%20status");

var update_status = new Request({
    method: 'POST',
    url:    url
});

/* Set your own onload and onerror methods */
update_status.xhr.onload = function(e) {
  // do something
  /* Set request as done */
  update_status.setAsDone();
}
update_status.xhr.error = function(e) {
  // do something
  /* Set request as done */
  update_status.setAsDone();
}

/* Send the request (this will start max. 3 clients and it will queue all other request till user is authorized */
RequestCountLimiter.add(update_status);
RequestCountLimiter.checkState();
```

There are a few more attempts but I deleted the code.

What is the best way to authenticate a user for social media on Appcelerator Titanium?

Comment: check App Transport Security section in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html

Comment: It [looks like|https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=no+valid+request+transport+found] this does not come from Titanium. The only thing I found on Google was [this|https://scn.sap.com/thread/3154540]. So I assume this comes from the server or a proxy in between.